# Load external web applications on a MVC3 Main application - Intranet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

I have a web application (MVC3) that is an Intranet, Main app. The solution is called Intranet and it has different projects. This web has two zones: a main div (work zone) and a menu to load other web applications.

I want to create other applications outside the Intranet project, they can be big and very different, with menus, views, ... I want to "call" these web applications from the menu of the Main app (Intranet), and I want to load these in the main div of the Main app.

I have two questions:
- With this architecture, how can I load applications on the Main application.
- Is this a good architecture? Other options: Areas, iframe,...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about sharing same data across different applications with different UI, I would create a service which returns the data and will access from the client apps which i want and show then in the relevant UI format.

If you want to showt he pages from a differnet web application, you can do any one of these

1) Use Iframe to show the content of an external page

2) Open  a new window using javascript window.open  and load the external page there

Comment: Thanks Shyju!I undrestan that there aren't any options to call MVC applications in the same server using C# or Razor instruction, isn't it?

Comment: @If you want to show the page of different app, you should opt for iFrame.